# Are MachineBasicBlocks supposed to implicitly fall through to their successors?

Tags: llvm, codegen

I'm debugging an LLVM target backend, and I am chasing a problem where a certain basic block ends up jumping to "nothing", i.e. just after the end of the function, when compiled with optimizations turned on.

One thing I noticed is that after instruction selection, the machine basic block has a successor but no instruction to actually jump there:

```
BB#1: derived from LLVM BB %switch.lookup
    Predecessors according to CFG: BB#0
        %vreg5<def> = SEXT %vreg2, %SREG<imp-def,dead>; DLDREGS:%vreg5 GPR8:%vreg2
        %vreg6<def,tied1> = ANDIWRdK %vreg5<tied0>, -2, %SREG<imp-def,dead>; DLDREGS:%vreg6,%vreg5
        %vreg7<def> = LDIWRdK 4; DLDREGS:%vreg7
        %vreg8<def> = LDIRdK 0; LD8:%vreg8
        %vreg9<def> = LDIRdK 1; LD8:%vreg9
        CPWRdRr %vreg6<kill>, %vreg7<kill>, %SREG<imp-def>; DLDREGS:%vreg6,%vreg7
        %vreg0<def> = Select8 %vreg9<kill>, %vreg8<kill>, 1, %SREG<imp-use>; GPR8:%vreg0 LD8:%vreg9,%vreg8
    Successors according to CFG: BB#2(?%)
```

I see similar ISel results from the x86 LLVM backend and the end result doesn't have a jump-to-nothingness, so I assume this, on its own, is not a problem:

```
BB#1: derived from LLVM BB %switch.lookup
    Predecessors according to CFG: BB#0
        %vreg7<def> = MOVSX32rr8 %vreg3; GR32:%vreg7 GR8:%vreg3
        %vreg8<def,tied1> = AND32ri %vreg7<tied0>, 65534, %EFLAGS<imp-def,dead>; GR32:%vreg8,%vreg7
        %vreg9<def,tied1> = SUB32ri8 %vreg8<tied0>, 4, %EFLAGS<imp-def>; GR32:%vreg9,%vreg8
        %vreg0<def> = SETNEr %EFLAGS<imp-use>; GR8:%vreg0
    Successors according to CFG: BB#2(?%)
```

So my question is: **What is the mechanism by which these CFG-specified successors are supposed to be turned into real jumps?** Does the x86 backend implement something special for this to work that the backend I'm debuggig doesn't?

Should I change my `ISelLowering` class to lower `Select8` into something that ends with an explicit jump, or is that unnecessary (maybe potentially even detrimental for some optimization to kick in) and there's some other magic that I need to do so that these implicit successors are correctly lowered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is perfectly valid for a MachineBasicBlock to fall through to the next Block](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-May/112903.html):

> That is valid. Passes that want to reorder basic blocks should only do
>   so if the `AnalyzeBranch` and related target hooks (`Insert`/`Remove`) allow
>   it.